# Table Value function and commands inside of it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have programmed a function with 
1) Create Table in Tempdb

1. Create Table in Tempdb
2. Create Table Value
3. while , If commands
4. Delete values from Table
5. Inserting values into above tables
6. Checking existence of table

   ```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Results
   ```

inside of it.
The results are in Temp tables show be backed

can I use a Table Value function for it? or it just should an insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I use a Table Value function for it? or it just should an insert

No, `DML` functions are not allowed inside a function. You need to use a stored procedure to perform the operations you have mentioned.

Read following link for more details on what is allowed and not allowed in a function.

[SQL SERVER – User Defined Functions (UDF) Limitations](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-user-defined-functions-udf-limitations/)